# how to apply a function to a row if the value of the column has a value in pandas

Tags: pandas, conditional-statements

i only want to apply a function to each row if the col1 contains the value '12'. for rows that don't have 12, return 0 on col3

I only want to apply the following to rows that have col1 = 12.

df['col3'] = df['col2'].str.lower().str.contains('apple',na=0)

```
d1
col1    col2
12      apple
13      apple
12      grape
```

Expected results..

```
df1
col1    col2    col3
12      apple   True
13      apple   False
12      grape   False
```

Thanks

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking... could you explain a little better? Maybe add a input and expected output? Or is this data frame the expected output already ? What does `apple` have to do with the number 12?

Comment: i updated my question. col1 is the sourceID and apples are coming from that source. so i want to apply to rows with col1 that has the value of 12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
df['col3'] = (df['col1'] == 12) & (df['col2'].str.contains('apple'))
```

Output:

```
  col1   col2   col3
0   12  apple   True
1   13  apple  False
2   12  grape  False
```

Answer (score 2):

Can do simply

```
df['col3'] = df['col1'].eq(12) & df['col2'].str.contains('apple')
```

Or in two steps separately

```
s = df.loc[df.col1.eq(12), 'col2'].str.lower().str.contains('apple',na=0)
df.loc[:, 'col32'] = s
df = df.fillna(False)
```